# MS Word 2003 on open custom property value increment

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2003

I have a Word document where I've created a custom property (File > Properties > Custom)

Name: autoInc

Type: Number

Value: 999

I want to know how to auto increment the value by 1 and override the current value every time this file is being saved.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Document_Save` Event, and in it increment the value.  A great link to doing that is [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/docprop.aspx) (and a little too complicated to post an excerpt).

Though if you wanted to just do it simply, I think this will work:

```
ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("autoInc").Value =  
  ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("autoInc").Value +  1
```